# What is the MS Access SQL equivalent of FULL OUTER JOIN with a.key IS NULL and b.key IS NULL

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet-sql

**Example Query** that I want to execute in MS Access SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA AS a
FULL OUTER JOIN TableB AS b
ON a.key = b.key
WHERE a.key IS NULL
OR b.key IS NULL
```

Since MS Access SQL does not allow FULL OUTER JOIN, I tried using the code below but the results aren't right.

```
SELECT *
FROM (TableA AS a
LEFT JOIN TableB AS b
ON a.key = b.key)
RIGHT JOIN TableB AS c
ON a.key = c.key
WHERE b.key IS NULL
OR a.key IS NULL
```

Does anyone know how to construct the MS Access SQL equivalent of the **Example Query** above that I'm trying to execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
select . . . 
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.key = a.key)
union all
select . . .
from b
where not exists (select 1 from a where a.key = b.key);
```

The `. . .` is for the columns that you want.

You could use `*` if you used:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a left join
     b
     on 1 = 0
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.key = a.key)
union all
select a.*, b.*
from b left join
     a
     on 1 = 0
where not exists (select 1 from a where a.key = b.key);
```

Comment: This works! Thanks so much! But I'm wondering, when would I use one over the other? Is it just preference or is there a performance difference or something else that I'm not aware of? Thanks again!

Comment: @KristinWong . . . Use the first form if you are comfortable listing the columns.  The second is just a way for you to use `*` so you don't have to list the column names.